# 500 error after changing directory permission on wordpress

Tags: linux, file-permissions, wordpress, cpanel

I changed the permission of uploads directory of wordpress on cpanel file manager. After that my site started to give 500 error on homepage. I didn't do anything else. After that I changed the permission the previous state. Nothing changed. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Its not your fault:

**Solution 1:** Wait

As per HTML Error Lists go, 500 is a server-side error. Meaning it can range in anything from the server running out of RAM or being overloaded by users or anything really.

It could also be the server is having problems processing the directory change. But don't worry, WordPress's engine is built ideally to deal with common errors such as this.

**Solution 2:** Process something else

If the errors continue, I suggest adding another blank file or directory. It maybe because the server has not noticed the error and/or has stopped processing requests. So maybe adding another request will get another server to deal with the error.

**Solution 3:** Restart

I don't know much about the CPanel in WordPress but if its anything like the CPanel's i've used. I would just stop the server and restart.